# Are the 3 generations of matter somehow connected to 3 dimensions of space?

Tags: standard-model, spacetime-dimensions

I notice that each generation of matter is associated with a Lie group with that many degrees of freedom. Does that imply that 3 generations of matter is a direct result of 3 spatial dimensions?

Comment: This is numerology. Similar question: [Why are there 4 Dimensions and 4 Fundamental Forces?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22067/2451)

Answer (score 0):

Right now we simply don't know why there are three generations of particles.

There are no theories (well, no *credible* theories) linking it to the dimensionality of spacetime. The closest we have is in String Theory where the number of dimensions is related to the topology of the Calabi-Yau manifold on which the theory is compactified. Whether this proves to be the correct explanation remains to be seen.