# Why does angular velocity lies in the axis passing through the center of the circumference?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotation, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I understand that it can't be placed anywhere on the radius because it doesn't vary with it ( and so of course it doens't make sense to place it anywhere else on the plane), but why do we place it there?

I undertand all the advantages that came *after* 
$$\vec v = \vec\omega\times\vec r$$
$$\vec a = \vec\alpha\times\vec r + \vec\omega\times\vec v$$

but I can't see what's before.

PS. I know there is another question opened: [Direction of angular velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69345/direction-of-angular-velocity) but I don't understand the answers given there (it's stated that angular velocity *points in every direction of the circumference's plane*!?) and I can't comment yet so please don't close this one. Thank you.

Comment: Other parts than center, have both angular and linear velocities. Center only has angular one, with respect to reference frame which is center axis.

Comment: I apologize domenicop, but realized I supplied you with a phony explanation! I've accordingly deleted my answer, and I apologize for misleading you. Real answer is on the way, unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik why do you say that other parts have both velocities and the center has not. Could you please elaborate better?

Comment: @DavidH I liked your answer. I don't think it's what I could say to my prof if asked at an exam, but it made calm the chaos in my head. It was a little i-don't-know-were-to-put-it-so-I-put-it-there though :) Have you elaborated a new answer by now? :)