# What kind of physical quantity is angular displacement?

Tags: vectors, tensor-calculus, rotational-kinematics, displacement

Angular Displacement is neither a vector nor a scalar.

What type of physical quantity it is? Are there any other examples of that physical quantity?

Comment: Was your question answered?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69345/2451

Answer (score 5):

Angular displacement is an example of what's generally called a [pseudovector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector). This is a quantity that is similar to a regular vector, except for the fact that it behaves differently under [improper rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_rotation) such as reflections (it gains an additional sign flip). Any quantity which is the cross-product of two polar vectors will generally be a pseudovector. Other examples include magnetic fields, angular momentum, torque and vorticity.