# Can't we assign any other direction for instantaneous angular velocity except along the axis of rotation?

Tags: vectors, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

We specify the direction of instantaneous angular velocity using the right hand thumb rule.
I just want to know that is it just a matter of convention or we don't have any other direction for it to be specified?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direction of angular velocity](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69345/)

Comment: The only plausible other convention would be the left hand thumb rule. There's no consistent way of defining it in some sort of momentary tangential velocity way, as any tangent vector in 3d might be rotating around an infinite number of axes.