# First integrals for a particle in a central-force field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

Consider an arbitrary dimension $n>3$. What are the independent first integrals for a particle?

The Hamiltonian is

$$ H = \frac{p^2}{2m} +V (|r|) . $$

Comment: Angular momentum

Comment: But what is it in higher dimensions?

Comment: The angular momentum can be obtained by $L_{ij} = r_i p_j - r_j p_i$. Remember that the angular momentum is not a real vector but a Pseudo-vector. You can read this page http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9864/how-to-define-angular-momentum-in-other-than-three-dimensions

Comment: Yes, it is straightforward to check that they are first integrals. But, there is some problem. There are $n(n-1)/2$ such quantities, while the degrees of freedom of the system is just $n$!

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that they are not commutative.