# Higher dimensional relation between angular momentum, moment of intertia and angular velocity

Tags: angular-momentum, tensor-calculus, rotational-kinematics, spacetime-dimensions, angular-velocity

In 3 dimensions we have the well known relation (summation convention is being used)

$$
L_i = I_{ij} \omega_j
$$

However, as is well known the angular momentum and angular velocity are not vectors but tensors and their Hodge duals are what are used in the above expression. So using the actual 2-forms 
$$
\tilde L_{ij} = \epsilon_{ijk} L_k~,
$$

and likewise for $\tilde \omega$, we get the above relation as

$$
\tilde L_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} ~I_{kl} ~\epsilon_{kij}~\epsilon_{lmn} ~\tilde \omega_{mn}
$$

My question is how do I generalize this to higher dimensions? The angular momentum, moment of inertia and angular velocity will remain second order tensors. However, in higher dimensions the Levi-Civita tensor will be of higher order and I cannot seem to find an unambiguous way to get a $3^rd$ order Levi-Civita tensor from a higher order one.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9864/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I think you need to consider that angular momentum in an arbitrary location then you use a cross product in 3D to do the parallel axis theorem. But in higher dimensions you would need to transition to the [wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra). Then you can decompose it into components using tensor  notations.

Comment: @Qmechanic while the link you mentioned is related in that it talks about angular momentum in higher dimensions, I don't think deals with relation between angular momentum and angular velocity. If you think there is some connection to angular velocity could you please point it out? Thanks.

Comment: @ja72 You are talking about the definition of angular momentum $\tilde L_{ij}=x_i p_j - x_j p_i$. That is included in my question when I mention the 3-d angular momentum 'vector' is a Hodge dual of $\tilde L_{ij}$. My question is not about this topic. My question is how to express angular momentum in terms of angular velocity.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out the answer is rather simpler in higher dimensions. It gets complicated when specializing to 3-dimensions.

If a rigid body has angular velocity $\omega_{ij}$ then given the location of a point $r_i$ its velocity is given by

$$
v_i = -\omega_{ij} r_j 
$$

and its angular momentum is given by

$$
L_{ij} =\sum m(r) ( -r_i v_j +r_j v_i )\\
= \sum m(r)( r_i r_m \omega_{mj} -r_j r_m \omega_{mi}) \\
$$

Specializing to 3D we get
$$
\tilde L_k = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{kij} L_{ij}\\
=\epsilon_{mjt}\epsilon_{ijk} [\sum m(r) r_i r_m] \tilde \omega_t \\
= -\delta^{tm}_{ik} [\sum m(r) r_i r_m ] \tilde \omega_t \\
= [\sum m(r) (-r_k r_i +r^2 \delta_{ki})] \tilde \omega_i \\
= I_{ki} \tilde \omega_i
$$

Thus we see that in arbitrary dimensions the relation between angular momenta, moment of inertia and angular velocity is given by

$$
L_{ij} =  2 \tilde I_{im} \omega_{mj}
$$

where $\tilde I_{ij} = \sum m(r) r_i r_j$.

Comment: $L_{ij} \neq 2 [\sum m(r) r_i r_m] \omega_{mj} = 2 \tilde I_{im} \omega_{mj}$. The rhs isn't generally antisymmetric. I think $L_{ij} = \tilde I_{im} \omega_{mj} - \tilde I_{jm} \omega_{mi}$ is correct, or $L = \tilde I \omega + \omega \tilde I$ in matrix notation. Another problem with this approach is it isn't clear that principle moments of inertia exist, or what they are. The rank-4 tensor in Sergio's answer is the real generalization of the inertia tensor, but has the disadvantage of being rank 4 of course.

Answer (score 5):

### 3D common way

Definition of angular momentum vector ($m = 1$) 
\begin{equation}
L_l = \epsilon_{lij}x^iv^j
\end{equation}
($L_l$ dual to $L^{ij} = x^iv^j - x^jv^i$ tensor)

Rortational velocity of particle 
\begin{equation}
 v^j = \epsilon^{jrk}\omega_rx_k.
\end{equation}
($\omega_r$ dual to $\omega^{jk}$ antisymmetric tensor of angular velocity $ \epsilon^{jrk}\omega_r = \omega^{jk}$)

Substitute in the angular momentum definition
\begin{equation}
 L_l = \epsilon_{lij}x^i\epsilon^{jrk}\omega_rx_k.
\end{equation}

Let us use the property of the Levi-Civita tensor:
\begin{equation}
 \epsilon^{lij} = -\epsilon^{jli}
\end{equation}

then

\begin{equation}
 L_l = - \epsilon_{jli}\epsilon^{jkr}x^ix_k\omega_r.
\end{equation}

Let us use another property of the Levi-Civita tensor:
\begin{equation}
 \epsilon_{jli}\epsilon^{jkr} = \delta_l^k\delta_i^r - \delta_l^r\delta_i^k.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 L_l = \left( \delta_l^r\delta_i^k - \delta_l^k\delta_i^r \right)  x^ix_k\omega_r.
\end{equation}

Expand the brackets and take into account that $\delta_i^r x^i = x^r$, $\delta_l^k x_k = x_l$ and $\delta_i^k x^i = x^k$, we get
\begin{equation}
 L_l = \left(  \delta_l^r x^kx_k - x^rx_l\right) \omega_r,
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
 L_l = \left(  \delta_l^r x^2 - x^rx_l\right) \omega_r,
\end{equation}

where inertia tensor
\begin{equation}
 I_l^r = \delta_l^r x^2 - x^rx_l
\end{equation}

### Arbitrary number of dimensions

For Higher dimensions we can use directly angular momentum tensor 
\begin{equation}
 L^{ij} = x^iv^j - x^jv^i
\end{equation}
and
Rortational velocity of particle we can express via angular momentum tensor 
\begin{equation}
 v^j = \omega^{jm}x_m.
\end{equation}

Then

\begin{equation}
 L^{ij} = x^ix_m\omega^{jm} - x^jx_m\omega^{im}
\end{equation}

Now we can lower indices near $\omega$ with metric tensor:
\begin{align}
 \omega^{jm} = g^{jn}g^{mr}\omega_{nr} \\
 \omega^{im} = g^{in}g^{mr}\omega_{nr} 
\end{align}

So, we get

\begin{equation}
 L^{ij} = \left( x^ix_mg^{jn}g^{mr} - x^jx_m g^{in}g^{mr}\right) \omega_{nr}
\end{equation}

So, we can conclude $L^{ij} = I^{ijnr} \omega_{nr}$, the inertia tensor is

\begin{equation}
 I^{ijnr} = x^ix_mg^{jn}g^{mr} - x^jx_m g^{in}g^{mr}
\end{equation}

Comment: This doesn't agree with equation (A2) in https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.03560.

Comment: Oh, I see, you haven't antisymmetrized over the pairs $i,j$ and $n,r$. I think this tensor is probably physically equivalent to the one in the source above, since you only plug in an antisymmetric 2-form $\omega$, as long as you remember to then only use the antisymmetric part of the output. Also, you forgot to weight the sum by the particle masses.

Comment: I prefer the form in the source above though, because it makes it clear which are the physically significant degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.03560, the appropriate generalization is
$$L_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} I_{ijkl} \omega_{kl},$$
where $L$ is the angular momentum two-form (which in three dimensions is the Hodge dual to the angular momentum vector), $\omega$ is the angular velocity two-form (likewise), and $I$ is the rank-four tensor of inertia defined by
$$I_{ijkl} := 4 \int dm \left( x_{[j} \delta_{i][k} x_{l]} \right).$$

Interestingly, the tensor of inertia has the same symmetries and number of degrees of freedom as the Riemann curvature tensor. ([This paper](https://physics.byu.edu/docs/publication/485) (PDF) tries to explain the reason behind this surprising parallel, but it uses some obscure math involving the geometric algebra, and I personally don't find it particularly illuminating.)

Comment: You don't need to cite a paper for it. I derived the same result in the answer above. It's a three line derivation.

Comment: @BorunChowdhury Your derivation is incorrect and gets a totally different result from the one in my answer. The moment of inertia tensor in general dimensions is rank-4, not rank-2 as in your answer.