# How to get Levi-Cevita symbol in the derivation for angular momentum using Noether's theorem? (David Tong Ex Sheet 1 Q6)

Tags: angular-momentum, field-theory, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

Working through David Tong's sheet here https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/oh1.pdf and can't follow  how to get the Levi-Cevita symbol out the front? Its equation 15.
I was looking at trying to use an identity with the Kronecker Deltas in the energy momentum tensor but I am really stuck. Below is the conserved charge, where does the $\epsilon_{ijk}$ come from?

$$Q_i = \epsilon_{ijk} \int d^3x (x^jT^{0k} - x^kT^{0j})$$

I can follow up to the conserved current and get the correct value for charge but I am missing the Levi-Cevita

Comment: it's just the cross product.  The expression is just a fancy way of writing $({\vec x} \times {\vec p})_{i}$

Comment: To be specific, $(\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b})^i = \epsilon_{ijk} a^j b^k$

Comment: @JerrySchirmer thanks, I feel silly asking this but where exactly does the cross product come into this? I've tried expanding by substituting in what I know $T^{0k}$  is but its getting kinda messy

Comment: @NiharKarve thanks, where are you getting the cross product in the equation? I'm a bit stuck still sorry, i have the conserved current $j^\mu$ but struggling to use the Levi-Civita still in the charge

Comment: @milkybean: $T^{0k}$ is the same thing as the three-momentum ${\vec p}^{k}$.  Then, remember that determinant rule for calculating the cross product?  Well, the signs in the terms in the determiant alternate in exactly the same way that $\epsilon_{ijk}$ do, right?  So, the $x$ component of ${\vec a} \times {\vec b}$ is $a_{y}b_{z} - a_{z}b_{y}$, for example.  Put it all together, and you can work out that the $i$ component of ${\vec a} \times {\vec b}$ is $\epsilon_{ijk}a^{j}b^{k}$

Comment: Luboš Motl's excellent answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9864/how-to-define-orbital-angular-momentum-in-other-than-three-dimensions) explains the difference between $L_{ij}$ and $L_k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conserved quantity that arises due to spatial rotational invariance is
$$
L^{jk} = Q^{jk} = \int \mathrm{d}^3 x\ (x^j T^{0k} - x^k T^{0j})
$$

Unlike the classical angular momentum pseudovector $\mathbf{x \times p}$, this is expressed as a matrix:

$$
L^{ij} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & L_{xy} & L_{xz} \\ -L_{xy} & 0 & L_{yz} \\ -L_{xz} & -L_{yz} & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

whose components may look familiar - they are similar to the magnetic field components in the electromagnetic field tensor $F^{jk}$. Again, similar to the electromagnetic case, to convert $L^{jk}$ back into the classical vector form, you have to use the Levi-Civita symbol:
$$
L_i = \epsilon_{ijk}L^{jk}
$$

However, as Luboš Motl remarks [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9864/how-to-define-orbital-angular-momentum-in-other-than-three-dimensions), it is usually more efficient to leave it tensor form.