# Moment of Inertia of Higher Dimensional Objects

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, spacetime-dimensions, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I would like to take on the mathematical exercise of deriving expressions for the moment of inertia of higher dimensional *solids*. But could there be any real world utility to it? If yes, which fields and perhaps pray elaborate on the *how*. If no, why not?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9864/2451

Comment: Covariances of more than three random variables in statistics are higher dimensional moments of inertia.

Comment: Related, at least for one of the simpler cases. [Moment of inertia of an n dimensional sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565333/moment-of-inertia-of-a-n-dimensional-sphere)